# Request Data to Model Function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to find out why when I `dd($request->all())` in the **store method of my controller** everything is correct, however when I send it to the model function `register()` its no where to be seen.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('delete', $user);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstName' => 'required|min:3',
            'lastName' => 'required|min:3',
            'displayName' => 'required|min:3',
            'emailAddress' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:3',
            'role' => 'required|exists:roles,id'
        ]);

        $userRegistered = $user->register(
            new User($request->all())
        );

        if ($userRegistered) {
            flash()->success('Success', 'The user has been successfully created!');
        } else {
            flash()->error('Error', 'The user could not be successfully created!');
        }

        return redirect()->to(route('users'));
    }
}




<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * Fillable fields for a user.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'display_name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'role_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function register(User $user)
    {
        return $user->create([
            'first_name' => $user->firstName,
            'last_name' => $user->lastName,
            'display_name' => $user->displayName,
            'email' => $user->emailAdress,
            'password' => $user->password,
            'role_id' => $user->role
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed up the formatting of your variables between your request data and your User model.

According to your validation logic, the request data is coming is as `camelCase`. Yet, according to your `$fillable` array, the fields on your User model are `snake_case`. But, even then, in your `register` method, you're attempting to access the fields on the User model using `camelCase`.

You haven't given enough information for a definitive answer, but you need to fix the formatting of your variables. For example, change your request fields names from `camelCase` to `snake_case`, and make sure you access your fields on the model using `snake_case`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a list of attributes to "validate" method.

```
//...
$this->validate($request->all(), [
    'firstName' => 'required|min:3',
    'lastName' => 'required|min:3',
    'displayName' => 'required|min:3',
    'emailAddress' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
    'password' => 'required|min:3',
    'role' => 'required|exists:roles,id'
]);
```

One more thing..check if you are using `"web"` middleware. (Kernel.php => MiddlewareGroups). Add that middleware to your route.

Comment: My validation runs correctly the way it is. What's different between yours and mine?